# What is the meaning of (`addTwo` 4) 5?

Tags: haskell

With a simple Haskell adder function

```
addTwo:: Num a => a -> a -> a
addTwo a b = a + b
```

and following expressions

```
addTwo 4 5 -- yields 9
4 `addTwo` 5 -- yields 9
(`addTwo` 4) 5 -- yields 9
```

I understand the first two expressions. However, how does the third one work? Does the expression `` (`addTwo` 4) `` become a function of one argument? What is the general principle here?

Comment: `addTwo 4 5` is the same as ``(`addTwo` 5) 4`` in the same way that `(+) 4 5` is equivalent to `(+ 5) 4`. Addition is commutative so ``(`addTwo` 4) 5`` is the same but here the first argument is 5: `addTwo 5 4`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Does the expression `` (`addTwo` 4) `` become a function of one argument?

Yes, this is exactly what happens. This is exactly the same as any other [operator section](https://wiki.haskell.org/Section_of_an_infix_operator) like `(+4)`, just using backticks instead of some other infix operator. In general, `` (a `op`) `` is the same as `` \x -> a `op` x ``, while `` (`op` a) `` is the same as `` \x -> x `op` a ``.